# Datagrid bound list not being updated visually from Popup Window event wpf

Tags: wpf, datagrid

This seems like a simple problem, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

I had a datagrid in wpf bound to a command that deleted everything in the datagrid. The command updated both in the data and visually. However, since it would not be wise to delete everything without a confirmation window, I changed the button to open a DeleteAllLinesConfirmation window.

Now, when I call the same function from the new confirmation window, it updates the data, but the grid does not update visually. I've tried calling OnPropertyChanged from the view of the popup window, and I verified the set where OnPropertyChanged resides is getting called properly. I just have no idea why it won't update. Is it because the old view is no longer in focus?

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, I would guess that it is indeed a focus issue. Try using a standard MessageBox instead. It should keep your focus a lot tighter than a window and allow your code to execute entirely within DeleteEverything(). You can use the MessageBoxResult to determine whether or not to actually delete everything inside DeleteEverything() after MessageBox.Show("blahblahblah") has returned.